# jni xlib Window handle

Tags: java, java-native-interface, xlib

using jawt jni library in the jdk, I can draw from C on an AWT canvas...

however what I need is an Xlib Window handle

the jawt_X11DrawingSurfaceInfo struct
provides an xlib VisualID handle, can this be turned into a Window handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [JNA library](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/native/dispatch.c#L2921) source, they're using `drawable` field in `JAWT_X11DrawingSurfaceInfo` to return window handle for xlib.

Comment: so drawable is the same as Window then? or just in the context of JAWT_X11DrawingSurfaceInfo ,  to be honest though JAWT seemed clunky and I ended up making an custom window inside jni and using that with my EGL binding, I only need a whole window context or fullscreen context and don't need to share it with java gui widgets so its good enough...

Comment: @ChrisCamacho: Drawable can be either a Window or a Pixmap in xlib. I don't know if it's possible that drawable would return id of an offscreen buffer, instead of a window. It probably shouldn't, since all the buffering is supposed to be transparent to the user.